# Open pirobox lightbox on load instead of click

Tags: jquery, onload

I need help in opening a pirobox lightbox on a page load instead of clicking on it.

http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/index.php

Comment: I wan`t to open a pirobox lightbox when the page loads instead of clicking on the element.  I tried         $(document).ready(function () {
            function open_popup() {
                $('#Reiseangebote').click();
            }
        }); with body onload. but got no success

Comment: That's close! There, you're creating a function named `open_popup`, but you never call it.

Comment: body onload="open_popup()" is not a call?

Comment: Yes, but that function only exists within the code you showed me above. It's not a global function, if you like. You're mixing two different ways of performing on-load actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pirobox doesn't support this explicitly, but you can programmatically trigger a "fake" click onLoad.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#myId').click();
});
</script>

<body>
    <a href="big1.jpg" rel="single" class="pirobox" title="your title" id="myId">
        <img src="small1.jpg"  />
    </a>
</body>
```

Here's a fixed version of your original approach (though I *do not recommend* using inline Javascript like this!):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_popup() {
   $('#myId').click();
}
</script>

<body onload="open_popup()">
    <a href="big1.jpg" rel="single" class="pirobox" title="your title" id="myId">
       <img src="small1.jpg"  />
    </a>
</body>
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work with "faking" the link while clicking still works

Comment: after inserting the function into the linked js-file, it worked... thx

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and this does not work for me at all

Comment: @NickDarley: With that level of detail, there is zero chance of anybody being able to help you.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903997/simulate-link-click-from-function/16904192?noredirect=1#comment24396679_16904192