# Simulate Link Click from Function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a webpage and I want to simulate a link click.

The way i have it setup is a user will click a link from an eblast that we are sending out and when the page loads the video will pop up of the link the picked.

Here is the website, and if you click on a image or title it pops up into a popup box. I am using prettyPhoto for this. 
http://dynamicdevsite.com/cmdnyc/audio-post-production-nyc.php

I have URL parser setup so my links look like this http://dynamicdevsite.com/cmdnyc/audio-post-production-nyc.php?ComedyCentral and the url parser sees ComedyCentral and then fires a function I have associated with that term and that fires just fine.

**Code for link click simulation**

```
function simulatedClick(target, options) {

        var event = target.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            options = options || {};

        //Set your default options to the right of ||
        var opts = {
            type: options.type                  || 'click',
            canBubble:options.canBubble             || true,
            cancelable:options.cancelable           || true,
            view:options.view                       || target.ownerDocument.defaultView, 
            detail:options.detail                   || 1,
            screenX:options.screenX                 || 0, //The coordinates within the entire page
            screenY:options.screenY                 || 0,
            clientX:options.clientX                 || 0, //The coordinates within the viewport
            clientY:options.clientY                 || 0,
            ctrlKey:options.ctrlKey                 || false,
            altKey:options.altKey                   || false,
            shiftKey:options.shiftKey               || false,
            metaKey:options.metaKey                 || false, //I *think* 'meta' is 'Cmd/Apple' on Mac, and 'Windows key' on Win. Not sure, though!
            button:options.button                   || 0, //0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right
            relatedTarget:options.relatedTarget     || null,
        }

        //Pass in the options
        event.initMouseEvent(
            opts.type,
            opts.canBubble,
            opts.cancelable,
            opts.view, 
            opts.detail,
            opts.screenX,
            opts.screenY,
            opts.clientX,
            opts.clientY,
            opts.ctrlKey,
            opts.altKey,
            opts.shiftKey,
            opts.metaKey,
            opts.button,
            opts.relatedTarget
        );

        //Fire the event
        target.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

function CC_Lightbox() {
      simulatedClick(document.getElementById("comedylink"));

}
```

**ERROR** 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

**Note:** I am sorry if this question is too localized, but I didn't know who/where else to ask at this point.

Comment: Is JQuery an option ?

Comment: There is a call to your function with `null` in the first argument somewhere.

Comment: well it seems there's no such dom object as `comedylink`. Are you sure you are using the `id` attribute to identify it and not the `name` one?

Comment: jQuery is an option i tried $("#comedylink").trigger("click");  and Yes i know for fact that my link has a ID of comedylink.

Comment: You might see more info on the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to do that

```
// change to this line
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

evt.initMouseEvent('click',true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

The first line should fix your code.

Then change

```
var event = target.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
```

to

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),
```

This should create the correct event and fix your

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
```

error.

Comment: and this will make my lightbox pop up?

Comment: and how would I implement it into my function?

Comment: I got this error which is the same but on a new line further down Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Comment: Replace `target.ownerDocument.defaultView` with `target`, it should work

Comment: on the second to last line of code i get this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'dispatchEvent' of null

Comment: at `target.dispatchEvent(event);`?  are you sure that `document.getElementById("comedylink")` exists?

Comment: that's correct and I know for a fact look --->   <a href="movies/CC_The%20Half%20Hour.mov" id="comedylink" class="bump" rel="720-480">Comedy Central</a>